# What should we use in place of getInnerHtml() and getOutterHtml() in Selenium?

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, protractor, deprecated

So selenium deprecated getInnerHtml() and getOutterHtml() and in 3.0 beta they plan on completely removing the functions. I have test that check markup. So what should we be using in their place? Why are they being removed? I use protractor/webdriver.js with selenium.

Comment: Maybe you [should provide feedback](https://seleniumhq.wordpress.com/2016/07/29/announcing-selenium-3-0-beta1/) :-)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`.getInnerHTML()` and `.getOuterHTML()` methods can be replaced with `.getAttribute("innerHTML")` and `.getAttribute("outerHTML")` respectively and, I assume, this is the reason they are deprecated. There is no point in having special methods for these cases while it can be easily retrieved through a "get attribute" call.

Note that `getInnerHTML()` and `getOuterHTML()` are not a part of the [Protractor public API](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api) anymore as well.

FYI, here are the [`getInnerHTML()` and `getOuterHTML()` method implementations](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/selenium-2.52.0/javascript/webdriver/webdriver.js#L2212) - basically retrieving the `innerHTML` and `outerHTML` attribute values (though for "outerHTML" there is a special case handling - when there is no `outerHTML` attribute available).

By the way, if you want to enforce not having `getInnerHTML()` and `getOuterHTML()` in your test codebase, you can use [`no-get-inner-outer-html` ESLint rule](https://github.com/alecxe/eslint-plugin-protractor/blob/master/docs/rules/no-get-inner-outer-html.md) from [`eslint-plugin-protractor` plugin](https://github.com/alecxe/eslint-plugin-protractor) (shameless self-promotion).